# why sublime text 3 output is showing wrong output but working fine on trinket code online

Tags: python

I have made a basic python code which is used for scraping but i am writing this code in sublime text which is showing the wrong output . But when i wrote code online then it is showing right output . I don't know why it is happening . I am new in python learning.
my python version .

```
python --version
3.8.10
```

Here is the output of code when i run it online

[image: This is the result which i want to achieve. It is the result when i run my code online]

[image]
This is the code output when run by sublime text 3.

Basically there should be **hiii** after every name of subject and after every present or absent. But sublime is not showing it correctly .
here is my code for.

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'
}
 
login_data = {
    'username': 'XXXX',
    'password': 'XXXX'
}
 
absent = 0
present = 0
def checker(check):
    if check=='present':
        print('hi')
        # global present
        # present += 1
    elif check=='absent':
        print('jdljdl')
        # global absent
        # absent+=1
 
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://app.bmiet.net/student/login"
    r =  s.get(url ,  headers =  headers)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
    login_data['_token'] = soup.find('input' , attrs ={'name' : '_token'} )['value']
    r =  s.post('http://app.bmiet.net/student/student-login', data = login_data ,  headers = headers  )
    r = s.get('http://app.bmiet.net/student/attendance/view' , headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
    result = soup.select('td')

    # result=list(map(lambda r:str(r.getText().lower()),result))
    date = []
    attendance = []
    no_of_lecture = []
    subject = []
    for x in result:
        print(x.getText())   
        print("hiii")
```

Can anybody help why it is not working in sublime text. And what can be done if don't want to install other ide for python.

Comment: This has nothing related to SublimeText which is only a text editor

Comment: @azro I know sublime is text editor and i configured it to run python . My friend also run this code and the code is working fine in his another ide but it should also work in sublime text which is not working.